# Can I filter an Access form based on a match criteria using VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, sorting, ms-access

I have created a form that acts like a more advanced find dialog box. The user clicks on a button within a form, which opens my search form. This search form filters the original form to only display records that match certain fields from the original record within a certain tolerance.

Is there a way to sort the filtered form to display the closest matches first? I have considered using a couple of helper fields within the form. These helper fields would be equivalent to the absolute value of the difference between my criteria and the data within the record's fields. However, I was unsure of whether there was a better way to approach the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to describe, how exactly you *only display records that match certain fields from the original record within a certain tolerance*.

Comment: So go give your idea a try and when you have code with issue, post question. Why do you need this sort in form? Really sounds like a report would be best vehicle for this output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly set the forms sort order quite much as easy to set the filter.

You might have say this:

```
Dim f             As String
Dim strWhere      As String   ' our filter
Dim strSortBy     As String   ' our sort by

f = "frmFilter"      ' name of our filter form.

DoCmd.OpenForm f, , , , , acDialog

If CurrentProject.AllForms(f).IsLoaded = False Then
  ' user closed the dialog form, so lets cancel
  Exit Sub
End If

' setup our form filter.
If IsNull(Forms(f)!CompanyName) = False Then
  ' user entered company name - filter by that
  ' match by starting
  strWhere = "CompanyName LIKE '" & Forms(f)!Company & "%'"
  strSortBy = "CompanyName"
End If

If IsNull(Forms(f)!City) = False Then
  ' user entered Persons name - filter by that
  strWhere = "LastName = '" & Forms(f)!LastName & "'"
  strSortBy = "City, LastName"
End If

' ok, done with that form, close it
DoCmd.Close acForm, f

Me.Filter = strWhere
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.OrderBy = strSortBy
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

For the dialog form to work (allow the code to continue?). The ok button on the dialog form will cause the code above to wait. So, to get "back" to this calling code, the ok button on the dialog form (the filter form) will have:

```
me.Visible = False
```

And the cancel button on the filter form will have:

docmd.Close acForm, me.Name

So, we assume that
If user hits ok on filter form - it is a "ok", and the form is STILL open. This allows our above code to use/look at/grab values from that dialog form.

If the user hits cancel in that dialog form, it is closed and once again our above code will run after the user closes that dialog form. So, closing the form means cancel, and setting visible = False means ok. (both actions (close, or visible = False) will flip the dialog form OUT of dialog mode and allow our above code to run after the open dialog form command we have above.

It is then a simple matter to get/grab values from the dialog form , setup our filter, and also setup our "order by"